# React setState() not updating state when button clicked

Tags: reactjs, chart.js

I'm new to React and trying to test some chart components using [react-chartjs-2](https://github.com/jerairrest/react-chartjs-2). I have two test data objects that I wish to toggle between when pressing an update button.

A main `App` component has been set up to handle the `Bar` (from react-chartjs-2) and the `Button` components. The `state` references the data object to use for `Bar`, and a variable `updated` is used to determine what data to show in the `handleUpdate()` method.

When the `Button` is clicked it should call the `handleUpdate()` method in `App`, which is passed down as a reference for `onClick` in props. The method evaluates `updated` and uses `setState()` to change the data being used. I'm using the callback of `setState()` to log the state and change the value of `updated`.

```js
    import React from 'react';
    import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
    import { Bar } from 'react-chartjs-2';

    const chart1 = {
      labels: ['Team1', 'Team2', 'Team3', 'Team4', 'Team5'],
      datasets: [{
        label: 'Team points',
        data: [503, 385, 270, 133, 65],
        backgroundColor: [
          '#4DB6AC',
          '#E57373',
          '#7986CB',
          '#F06292',
          '#E0E0E0'
        ]
      }]
    };

    const chart2 = {
      labels: ['Team1', 'Team2', 'Team3', 'Team4', 'Team5'],
      datasets: [{
        label: 'Team points 2',
        data: [303, 185, 470, 313, 65],
        backgroundColor: [
          '#4DB6AC',
          '#E57373',
          '#7986CB',
          '#F06292',
          '#E0E0E0'
        ]
      }]
    };

    class App extends React.Component {
      constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.handleUpdate = this.handleUpdate.bind(this);

        this.updated = false;

        this.state = {
          chartData: chart1
        }

        console.log(this.state.chartData);
        console.log(this.updated);
      }

      // Toggle between chart1 and chart2 based on value of updated
      handleUpdate() {

        if (!this.updated) {
          this.setState({
            chartData: chart2
          }, () => {
            console.log(this.state.chartData);
            this.updated = true;
          });
        }
        else {
          this.setState({
            chartData: chart1
          }, () => {
            console.log(this.state.chartData);
            this.updated = false;
          });
        }
      }

      render() {
        return(
          <div>
            <Bar data={this.state.chartData} width={650} height={400} />
            <Button handleOnClick={this.handleUpdate} />
          </div>
        );
      }
    }

    const Button = (props) => (
        <button id="update-chart" onClick={props.handleOnClick}>Update</button>
    );

    ReactDOM.render(
      <App />,
      document.getElementById('chart-container')
    );
```

The first time the button is clicked everything works as intended, the state is updated and the component re-renders to display the new data. However, on subsequent clicks the state remains the same and the chart continues to reference the same data.

[console output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FNceh.png) - the first object is the initial render, the subsequent two are logged after clicking the button. As you can see, the data does change on the first button click but not the second or any subsequent click.

I'm aware that `setState()` is asynchronous and may batch updates, but what I don't understand is why it works successfully on the first click but not every other click and why the callback is being called but the state hasn't changed.

**edit**: I think the problem is related to [react-chartjs-2](https://github.com/jerairrest/react-chartjs-2). If I remove the `import` statement to import the `Bar` component, and instead define `Bar` to be a regular function component unrelated to Chartjs, then the state of `App` successfully changes between the two data objects on each click.

So it seems to be related to passing the data prop into the `Bar` component from react-chartjs-2. Although I'm not sure why that stops the state of `App` from changing, since it's the top-level component.

[Here is a JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/38rr1udt/3/) showing how it works when not using `Bar` as a react-chartjs-2 component.

Comment: @Ved A duplicate for some who already knows what they're doing. OP obviously does not.

Comment: are there any warnings or error in console anytime ?

Comment: @Panther there are no errors. I included an image of the console output, the first data object is from the initial render, the other two objects are from the button clicks. The first click makes changes but the rest do not.

Comment: In regards to this being a duplicate I have checked that post and many others and most are just about setState being asynchronous and callbacks, which I'm using to log the changes.

Comment: @Andrew Sure. I removed the close vote.

Comment: @SmCTwelve when you click button second time, is the render() is getting called?

Comment: Can you put your code on codepen or jsfiddle?

Comment: @MatthewBarbara not sure how to make a JSFiddle that imports react-chartjs-2.

Comment: I've edited my post. The issue seems to be related to the react-chartjs-2 component I'm using.

Comment: `this.update` should be kept in state. That may be why it doesn't toggle again.

Answer (score 0):

I wish I could use this as a comment, but I am recreating exactly what you have and cannot replicate your error. Your code is hard to interpret and that might be throwing me/us off. This is my implementation of your `handleUpdate`

```
const chartData = this.updated ? chart2 : chart1
this.setState({chartData}, () => {
  this.updated = this.updated ? false : true
})
```

Comment: I changed `handleUpdate` to your code and it's still the same; state changes on the first button click only. Apologies if the code is hard to interpret though from what I can tell it's otherwise syntatically correct. Ideally I'd be pulling my chart data from elsewhere but this is just for testing.

Comment: you don't need a ternary here, you can do:
this.setState({
      updated:!updated,
    });